# ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (initbpy)

Tags: python

I want to access BPY in standard python console on windows 64bit operating system. 
I searched, and found this link "http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User%3aIdeasman42/BlenderAsPyModule". 
I did all the steps. but unable to import BPY in my python IDLE, also version of both are same. It shows error which is :"

`>>>` import bpy

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File `"<pyshell#1>"`, line 1, in `<module>`

```
import bpy
```

ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (initbpy)

please help me. 
thanks

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I also ran into this problem. I think Python3.x is needed or see bullet points below for more information.

Failed: python -c "import bpy; print('hello');"

Worked: python3 -c "import bpy; print('hello');"

- "get Python3.x-framework from Python.org and install it."
- "The Python version requirements are the same with building a regular blender binary (if Blender us using Python3.5 then there is NO WAY to use another version - 2.7/3.2/3.4 will all fail)."

Source: [https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User%3aIdeasman42/BlenderAsPyModule](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User%3AIdeasman42/BlenderAsPyModule)

Answer (score 0):

**Same Hassle on Ubuntu.**

As of a recent change circa a month or two ago my `bpy` build also started to fail importing with same error. (Test import from bin folder, after successful build,  before install)

```
>>> from bin import bpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_bpy)
```

As the error message suggests, and confirmed by running

```
$ nm -D bpy.so | grep PyInit_bpy
```

returning nada, whereas would expect something like

```
0000000002146787 T PyInit_bpy
```

*Getting the result above and finally importing were woohoo moments indeed.*

This came after searching high and low, throwing back quite a few red herrings, grinding through numerous updates, and so many re-builds,  finally came across a couple of leads on stack overflow.

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112375/so-module-doesnt-import-in-python-dynamic-module-does-not-define-init-function
>
> You need to either use a plain C compiler, or force C linkage
>   throughout your module with an extern "C" directive:

leading me to the python link flags.  Image from `cmake_gui`

[image]

The generated value for cmake entry  `PYTHON_LINKFLAGS` was

```
-Xlinker -export-dynamic
```

to

```
-Xlinker --export-dynamic -Xlinker -init=PyInit_bpy
```

fixed the issue for me and I can now import `bpy` in a python 3.8 shell.

```
$ python3.8
Python 3.8.2 (default, Apr  2 2020, 03:24:36) 
[GCC 7.5.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import bpy
>>>
```

I feel tho, that this is a bit "hackish".. anyone reading with a "cleaner" way to do same please edit into answer or add comment.