# Visual Studio can't read submodule definitions in Bpy

Tags: scripting, source-code

OS: Windows

Python version: 3.7.4  (is in path, system wide install)

Blender version: 2.83 (from current source)

Issue: I can't get Visual Studio to show code suggestions past the main bpy level. [image]

I followed the steps to build blender as a python module exactly but I can't seem to get it to work properly: https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Other/BlenderAsPyModule

How could I build bpy to work like any other library?

Importing bpy into python console works:

[image]

For reference, listing modules in the console shows these modules do exist
[image]

Comment: Can you confirm that `bpy` imports Ok into python console. Currently I am having issues with `bpy` build. Builds fine wont import.   Get this error https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90072/importerror-dynamic-module-does-not-define-init-function-initbpy

Comment: Updated the post @batFINGER

Comment: of more interest would be `import bpy`  Printing help modules works for me too, but importing doesn't. And without import no intellisense.

Comment: Can confirm import bpy works in console as well

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that for some reason the available docs don't work for Visual Studio Community, but they do work for VS Code.

I feel like VS Community just doesn't know where to look for the rest of the definitions bc if you move the entire 2.83 file from bin\Release\ to C:\Python37\, the IDE actually shows some code suggestions but not everything. At this point it's easier to just use VS Code for addon development and VS Community for blender development